# Escape semicolon route playframework 2.0.2

Tags: playframework, routes, playframework-2.0, uri

I would like to do a redirect function with playframework. So far I have this in my routes

```
GET     /redirect            com.test.redirect(redirecturl: String?="")
```

and my controller :

```
public static Result redirect(String redirecturl) { 
   return redirect(redirectURL); 
}
```

This is working well but I have a problem when I pass a url containing a semicolon ";"

If I go to

`http:localhost:9000/redirect?redirecturl=http://www.google.com;testaftersemicolon`

It redirect me to google.com but in my log the redirecturl is only equals to "http://www.google.com" stopping after a semicolon.

Is there a way to escape it ? Or to do a custom routing inside play?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to escape it by using a custom regular expression in the routes file. This is described in [the documentation about routing](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaRouting).
Basically something like the following should work:

```
GET     /redirect/$url<.+>            com.test.redirect(url: String?="")
```